# How to make selenium browser opened on Windows Monitor via SSH?

Tags: ssh, display

Here is the Situation

- I have macOS, Windows10
- OpenSSH server is opened in Windows10
- I wrote a python script to open a browser with selenium, which is stored in Windows10
- Now I want to access to Windows10 from macOS via SSH
- Connected! now run 'python script.py' from Terminal in macOS, which is connected to ssh server in Windows10
- But browser is not showing up in Windows10 Monitor
- If I run script in Windows10, typing with keyboard connected to desktop sitting in front of Windows10 Monitor, it properly works

How can I fix this? I don't even have a clue what's causing this problem

Comment: similar question : I want to turn off the Windows10 monitor via ssh and some script from macOS. But not working. How can I fix this?

Comment: Here is the script I tried : powershell (Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]^public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);' -Name a -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)